# How to make REST API private?

Tags: api, rest

APIs like googlemaps API of facebook API are public and can be consumed by anybody. So my question is how do you make REST API private so it can be consumed only by choosen one consumer. For example You make Rest API only for your pwn AngularJS app. Is it common to do this, what is real world approach for this? And in that matter is there any differences between REST API and REST Web Services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were to write a private RESTful API, I probably wouldn't bother to make it RESTful in the first place.

By making a REST API private, you're losing one of this architectural style's primary advantages. Implementing an API like this is difficult but in return you get the ease of scalability and the ability for the consumers of your API to write clients that are not likely to break because of future changes (as long as you follow [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) and use well-defined formats).

If you have the option to control both the service and all of its clients, giving up some of the constraints imposed by a RESTful architecture might actually be a good idea.

You should be fine with a simple API that serves JSON over HTTP as long as you stick to the protocol semantics.

In other words, you could implement a service that fulfils the requirements of a Level 2 API, as described by the [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html)

Because you wouldn't be making full use of the advantages offered by a Level 3 API, not to mention an actually RESTful API, implementing one could just prove an unnecessary effort.

I gave a more comprehensive description of these design considerations in [my answer to a programmers.stackexchange question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257447/56903). You can find some useful references in there as well.

Comment: hmmm so in real world scenarios for example if company is providing api for there web app and mobile app. What if somebody will make better web app using their API so all users will use this rather than client made by company that provided api and this is unwanted because the company will loose their earnings?

Comment: @bambuseq that's some very broad questions you're asking. It depends on how the company plans to monetize the API. Is the company planning to make money by selling the mobile app or displaying ads on the website? Is the use of the API going to be free or a paid service? These are obiously some considerations to make. However, they do not only concern REST APIs and they have as much (or possibly more) to do with the business model than the technology or architecture.

Comment: this is not an answer, at all, to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can make API private by requiring some authorization / authentication to use it (simple API keys for example).

> REST API vs REST Web Services?

Well, put it this way. REST Web services **have** REST APIs. Web service is a group of APIs united by purpose.